# Unable to render a view with app.get in Express

Tags: mongodb, express

I am trying to understand routes in express and I want to retrieve a document in my MongoDB database. I have established the database connection as follows:

```
//database object
var db

//Database Path
var dbpath =  process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds163758.mlab.com:63758/heroku_xv7rsvvw';

//Establish database connection
MongoClient.connect(dbpath, (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = database
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || theport, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  })
})
```

I want to gather my views from the "sections" collection in the MongoDB above so within an index.js that will then output the code into a jade/put template:

```
//find about
//2. Read the quotes from the collection
//3. Render them in index.ejs
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('sections').find({"name": "about"}).toArray((err, result) => {

    if (err) return console.log(err)
    // renders index.ejs
    res.render('about.jade#content', {sections: result})
    console.log(result)
  })
})
```

TEMPLATE (about.jade)

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  section
    h2 #{content}
```

sections document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "587dfdgf36d284ed58a9f69"
    },
    "name": "about",
    "tittle": "About Us",
    "summary": "WE KNOW HOW TO BUILD GREAT PRODUCTS",
    "content": "<p>Some features of the app and releasing it to the app store won\u2019t make it great. Lorem ipsom \u2019ll dolor bensulplin \u2013 hnlmops
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you get any result from your database query? Or any errors in console?

Comment: Yes, just a not found: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` but the connection is working and the collection is there.